# Align dropdown sub menu with parent menu width

Tags: html, css

I want to keep my dropdown menu inside body wrapper using jQuery, 
just tell me how dropdown menu of this mega-menu are inside body wrapper width

[see the demo here](http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-megamenu-2/)

screenShot:

in first example Dropdown menu is floating outside body wrap or body width. whereas in 2nd example dropdown menu is inside body wrapper.
I want to keep dropdown menu inside body wrapper, dropdown should not float outside body width

[image: menu]

Comment: What have to tried yet? elaborate the question if you can a little...

Comment: `ul > li { width:500px}` ? the parent element has a fixed width, CSS does the trick.

Comment: The submenu UL should automatically become as big as it's parent LI I think: http://jsfiddle.net/T52mX/

Comment: I still don't understand what the expected result is. Sorry. Maybe event a simple screnshot updated in mspaint for example would help to understand what the expected resut is to be.

Comment: can you post a demo in jsfiddle.net for us to work on?